# How do I disable Angular CLI from bundling js/css when running the Angular template in visual studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net, angular, webpack, bundling-and-minification

How do I disable Angular CLI from bundling js/css when running the Angular template project in visual studio 2017?

I notice that after running my solution, the following element is added right before the end of the head

```
<link href="styles.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

And this element right before the end of the body.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

I dont want to bundle anything, and instead want to use whatever CSS/JS is referenced in the actual html files. No optimization needed at this point in time.

Im using Visual Studio 2017 pro, v 15.8.0
and the Angular template that is created when creating a new project as shown below. 
[image: angular template]

Is this the angular CLI that is doing this??

UPDATE: Solved half the problem in answer below, still looking for the JS fix.

Comment: @R.Richards, there must be a way to disable it, Its illogical to Mandate bundling and minification. Im not running prod build, its running npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media

Comment: so based on what your saying, its difficult to simplify the creation of the final HTML that is served, based on how the CLI is designed along with the template..

Comment: @R.Richards, how about this then, how would I go about simply adding an override css to the final outputed bundled css that the CLI outputs? In other words, how does the CLI understand which files to contain in the final output styles.bundle.css?

Comment: @R.Richards, You were right about it being the Angular CLI. Ill give you that. But see my answer below, which discredits the claim that disabling the bundling is difficult. It was simply a command line arg to ng, perhaps its even the same for the JS bundling. You may want to update your answers. Misinformation is worse than no information.

Comment: interesting, according to a source "By using the Angular CLI you lose the ability to configure and customize webpack" https://hackernoon.com/webpack-for-angular-developers-c8584a60e627

Answer (score 1):

Solving half the problem here. In order to disable CSS bundling, all that is required is to ensure that .angular-cli.json styles node is empty as shown below

[image]
So that solves the CSS problem, 50% of the problem really.